# How can I set the default font size in aquamacs emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

I am having difficulty setting the default size in aquamacs emacs, under Lion.  If I add something like

```
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 180)
```

To my .emacs file, the default size of the **minibuffer** will be 18pt, but the other buffers will still open at the old default size.

Answer (score 2):

Options | Appearance | Font for Fundamental Mode (make sure you choose save options when quitting Aquamacs)

Answer (score 2):

In aquamacs, it is not intuitive (understatement).
Options> customise Aquaemacs>SPecific Face...
then type, "default", just as it said above. This gets you to the screen where you can look really hard to find the "Height in 1/10 point" value.

Good luck!

-TPC

Answer (score 1):

Probably the same way you do it for vanilla Emacs.

When you say "default" size, what do you mean?  If you mean the default for future Emacs sessions also, then  ***customize*** face `default`.  Function `set-face-attribute` does not set the face persistently.

If you mean set it only for the current Emacs *session*, and set it for all existing and all future frames, then your code looks correct to me.  In that case, consider filing a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Drew, I do mean to set the default for all future sessions. I don't quite understand your answer. Is there something I can put into my .emacs file to do this at startup? Googling for customize face only brings up things like "M-x customize-face RET default".

Comment: Yes, `M-x customize-face RET default`. Set the height you want. Save. Let me know if something is still unclear. See the Emacs manual, node `Face Customization`. That said, what you've done should also work, if you can do it early enough in each session.  But there is the initial frame, etc., and perhaps some things are displayed before that is being evaluated -- dunno.  You'd have to debug/experiment a bit to see what's happening.  But if you use Customize you should have no problem.